# ***Unable to Connect servlet methods in wicket through objectstream.***

Tags: spring, servlets, filter, wicket

I want to connect servlet using urlconnection in wicket-spring integration, but when i try to hit the url its redirecting to webapplication page, So can anyone tell me how to connect servlet methods by using filters or any other way, so that i can directly hit dopost or doget methods.

Comment: Please post your code and error messages and stack traces you get.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, so I'll try to guess. I suppose that you have a Wicket filter that intercepts and handles all the requests. Also you have some servlet, and you want requests to that servlet to not be intercepted by Wicket filter.

If this is what you want, here is what you can do to achieve this.

Let's say you have Wicket filter mapped to `/` and the servlet mapped to `/my-service`. Then you could tell Wicket filter to ignore requests to `/my-service` url:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>... some application class name ...</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ignorePaths</param-name>
        <param-value>/my-service</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

If you want several paths to be ignored, you can separate them with commas like this:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ignorePaths</param-name>
        <param-value>/my-service,/my-other-service</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

With this configuration, Wicket will ignore any requests under `/my-service` (that is, `/my-service`, `/my-service/blabla` and so on) and any request under `/my-other-service`.

Comment: Actually after working out some examples i could able to connect servlet doget(). when am logging into my solution, I have created a method in war login page which extends webpage, where am testing by calling my api to fetch the data through servlet, but when am calling api from other project by keeping war and jar in my server, its throwing null value at  
ois = new ObjectInputStream(urlconnection.getconnection()); 
String result = ois.readObject();
here the value of result am getting null value. Can you tell me how can i fetch values just like after logging in am able to fetch values.